# How to verify if a WCF net.pipe endpoint address is valid in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to create a tool which would check the Endpoint addresses defined in web.config file and validate if the address url of the WCF service is valid i.e service exists or not.

I am able to do it for http address but stuck on how to check the net.tcp address.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to check this is to call one of the methods on the endpoint.

If you want to do this, your service must have a specific method that you can call for this purpose. What I often do is have a method that returns the version information for a service, e.g.

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetVersion()
```

and I implement this on my services. To check whether the endpoint is OK, create a client-side proxy, and then call that method. If it works, then (and only then) your whole WCF setup is OK.